# no module named "torch" please

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch

Hello everyone please help me I have problem with import Torch, I have been tried everything what chat gpt told me. Creating new env and virtual env with python 3.9 and other versions.
Updated pip, conda, libmamba, github. I already don't know what to do. Please someone help me. One week I can not solve it.

```
(myenv) \_____\_ \~ % conda install pytorch::pytorch torchvision torchaudio -c pytorch
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): | WARNING conda.models.version:get_matcher(556): Using .\* with relational operator is superfluous and deprecated and will be removed in a future version of conda. Your spec was 1.7.1.*, but conda is ignoring the .* and treating it as 1.7.1
done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan

environment location: /Users/\___\_/anaconda3/envs/myenv

added / updated specs:
\- pytorch::pytorch
\- torchaudio
\- torchvision

The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    gmpy2-2.1.2                |   py39h2da61ea_1         166 KB  conda-forge
    markupsafe-2.1.3           |   py39hdc70f33_1          22 KB  conda-forge
    mkl-service-2.4.0          |   py39h6c40b1e_1          44 KB
    mkl_fft-1.3.8              |   py39h6c40b1e_0         195 KB
    mkl_random-1.2.4           |   py39ha357a0b_0         271 KB
    numpy-1.26.0               |   py39h827a554_0          11 KB
    numpy-base-1.26.0          |   py39ha186be2_0         6.7 MB
    pillow-10.1.0              |   py39hdd30358_0        44.2 MB  conda-forge
    pytorch-2.1.0              |          py3.9_0        84.0 MB  pytorch
    pyyaml-6.0.1               |   py39hdc70f33_1         159 KB  conda-forge
    torchaudio-2.1.0           |         py39_cpu         4.7 MB  pytorch
    torchvision-0.16.0         |         py39_cpu         6.6 MB  pytorch
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       147.0 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

aom                conda-forge/osx-64::aom-3.6.1-he965462_0
blas               pkgs/main/osx-64::blas-1.0-mkl
cairo              conda-forge/osx-64::cairo-1.18.0-h99e66fa_0
dav1d              conda-forge/osx-64::dav1d-1.2.1-h0dc2134_0
expat              conda-forge/osx-64::expat-2.5.0-hf0c8a7f_1
ffmpeg             conda-forge/osx-64::ffmpeg-6.0.0-gpl_h789aacd_105
filelock           conda-forge/noarch::filelock-3.12.4-pyhd8ed1ab_0
font-ttf-dejavu-s\~ conda-forge/noarch::font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono-2.37-hab24e00_0
font-ttf-inconsol\~ conda-forge/noarch::font-ttf-inconsolata-3.000-h77eed37_0
font-ttf-source-c\~ conda-forge/noarch::font-ttf-source-code-pro-2.038-h77eed37_0
font-ttf-ubuntu    conda-forge/noarch::font-ttf-ubuntu-0.83-hab24e00_0
fontconfig         conda-forge/osx-64::fontconfig-2.14.2-h5bb23bf_0
fonts-conda-ecosy\~ conda-forge/noarch::fonts-conda-ecosystem-1-0
fonts-conda-forge  conda-forge/noarch::fonts-conda-forge-1-0
freetype           conda-forge/osx-64::freetype-2.12.1-h60636b9_2
fribidi            conda-forge/osx-64::fribidi-1.0.10-hbcb3906_0
gettext            conda-forge/osx-64::gettext-0.21.1-h8a4c099_0
gmp                conda-forge/osx-64::gmp-6.2.1-h2e338ed_0
gmpy2              conda-forge/osx-64::gmpy2-2.1.2-py39h2da61ea_1
gnutls             conda-forge/osx-64::gnutls-3.7.8-h207c4f0_0
graphite2          conda-forge/osx-64::graphite2-1.3.13-h2e338ed_1001
harfbuzz           conda-forge/osx-64::harfbuzz-8.2.1-h7666e2a_0
icu                conda-forge/osx-64::icu-73.2-hf5e326d_0
jinja2             conda-forge/noarch::jinja2-3.1.2-pyhd8ed1ab_1
lame               conda-forge/osx-64::lame-3.100-hb7f2c08_1003
lcms2              conda-forge/osx-64::lcms2-2.15-hd6ba6f3_3
lerc               conda-forge/osx-64::lerc-4.0.0-hb486fe8_0
libass             conda-forge/osx-64::libass-0.17.1-h80904bb_1
libdeflate         conda-forge/osx-64::libdeflate-1.19-ha4e1b8e_0
libexpat           conda-forge/osx-64::libexpat-2.5.0-hf0c8a7f_1
libglib            conda-forge/osx-64::libglib-2.78.0-hc62aa5d_0
libiconv           conda-forge/osx-64::libiconv-1.17-hac89ed1_0
libidn2            conda-forge/osx-64::libidn2-2.3.4-hb7f2c08_0
libjpeg-turbo      conda-forge/osx-64::libjpeg-turbo-3.0.0-h0dc2134_1
libopus            conda-forge/osx-64::libopus-1.3.1-hc929b4f_1
libpng             conda-forge/osx-64::libpng-1.6.39-ha978bb4_0
libtasn1           conda-forge/osx-64::libtasn1-4.19.0-hb7f2c08_0
libtiff            conda-forge/osx-64::libtiff-4.6.0-h684deea_2
libunistring       conda-forge/osx-64::libunistring-0.9.10-h0d85af4_0
libvpx             conda-forge/osx-64::libvpx-1.13.1-he965462_0
libwebp-base       conda-forge/osx-64::libwebp-base-1.3.2-h0dc2134_0
libxcb             conda-forge/osx-64::libxcb-1.15-hb7f2c08_0
libxml2            conda-forge/osx-64::libxml2-2.11.5-h3346baf_1
llvm-openmp        conda-forge/osx-64::llvm-openmp-17.0.2-hff08bdf_0
markupsafe         conda-forge/osx-64::markupsafe-2.1.3-py39hdc70f33_1
mkl                conda-forge/osx-64::mkl-2023.2.0-hfe8bc8c_50499
mkl-service        pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl-service-2.4.0-py39h6c40b1e_1
mkl_fft            pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl_fft-1.3.8-py39h6c40b1e_0
mkl_random         pkgs/main/osx-64::mkl_random-1.2.4-py39ha357a0b_0
mpc                conda-forge/osx-64::mpc-1.3.1-h81bd1dd_0
mpfr               conda-forge/osx-64::mpfr-4.2.0-h4f9bd69_0
mpmath             conda-forge/noarch::mpmath-1.3.0-pyhd8ed1ab_0
nettle             conda-forge/osx-64::nettle-3.8.1-h96f3785_1
networkx           conda-forge/noarch::networkx-3.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0
numpy              pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy-1.26.0-py39h827a554_0
numpy-base         pkgs/main/osx-64::numpy-base-1.26.0-py39ha186be2_0
openh264           conda-forge/osx-64::openh264-2.3.1-hf0c8a7f_2
openjpeg           conda-forge/osx-64::openjpeg-2.5.0-ha4da562_3
p11-kit            conda-forge/osx-64::p11-kit-0.24.1-h65f8906_0
pcre2              conda-forge/osx-64::pcre2-10.40-h1c4e4bc_0
pillow             conda-forge/osx-64::pillow-10.1.0-py39hdd30358_0
pixman             conda-forge/osx-64::pixman-0.42.2-he965462_0
pthread-stubs      conda-forge/osx-64::pthread-stubs-0.4-hc929b4f_1001
pytorch            pytorch/osx-64::pytorch-2.1.0-py3.9_0
pyyaml             conda-forge/osx-64::pyyaml-6.0.1-py39hdc70f33_1
svt-av1            conda-forge/osx-64::svt-av1-1.7.0-he965462_0
sympy              conda-forge/noarch::sympy-1.12-pypyh9d50eac_103
tbb                conda-forge/osx-64::tbb-2021.10.0-h1c7c39f_1
torchaudio         pytorch/osx-64::torchaudio-2.1.0-py39_cpu
torchvision        pytorch/osx-64::torchvision-0.16.0-py39_cpu
typing_extensions  conda-forge/noarch::typing_extensions-4.8.0-pyha770c72_0
x264               conda-forge/osx-64::x264-1!164.3095-h775f41a_2
x265               conda-forge/osx-64::x265-3.5-hbb4e6a2_3
xorg-libxau        conda-forge/osx-64::xorg-libxau-1.0.11-h0dc2134_0
xorg-libxdmcp      conda-forge/osx-64::xorg-libxdmcp-1.1.3-h35c211d_0
yaml               conda-forge/osx-64::yaml-0.2.5-h0d85af4_2
zlib               conda-forge/osx-64::zlib-1.2.13-h8a1eda9_5

Proceed (\[y\]/n)? y

Downloading and Extracting Packages:

Preparing transaction: done  
Verifying transaction: done  
Executing transaction: done
```

python answer

```
(myenv) \____\_ \~ % python 
 
Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022, 12:41:40)
\[Clang 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.202)\] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import torch
> > > Traceback (most recent call last):
> > > File "\<stdin\>", line 1, in \<module\>
> > > ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
```

conda list

```
conda list

# packages in environment at /Users/\___\_/anaconda3/envs/myenv:

# 

# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel

aom                       3.6.1                he965462_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl  
boltons                   23.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli-python             1.1.0            py39h840bb9f_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h0d85af4_4    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2023.7.22            h8857fd0_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.18.0               h99e66fa_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2023.7.22          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.16.0           py39h18ef598_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        3.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
conda                     23.9.0           py39h6e9494a_0    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    2.2.0              pyh38be061_0    conda-forge
conda-package-streaming   0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cryptography              41.0.4           py39he8b0a07_0    conda-forge
dav1d                     1.2.1                h0dc2134_0    conda-forge
expat                     2.5.0                hf0c8a7f_1    conda-forge
ffmpeg                    6.0.0           gpl_h789aacd_105    conda-forge
filelock                  3.12.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.14.2               h5bb23bf_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.12.1               h60636b9_2    conda-forge
fribidi                   1.0.10               hbcb3906_0    conda-forge
fsspec                    2023.9.2                 pypi_0    pypi
gettext                   0.21.1               h8a4c099_0    conda-forge
gmp                       6.2.1                h2e338ed_0    conda-forge
gmpy2                     2.1.2            py39h2da61ea_1    conda-forge
gnutls                    3.7.8                h207c4f0_0    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.13            h2e338ed_1001    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  8.2.1                h7666e2a_0    conda-forge
icu                       73.2                 hf5e326d_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.1.2              pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
jsonpatch                 1.33               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jsonpointer               2.4              py39h6e9494a_3    conda-forge
lame                      3.100             hb7f2c08_1003    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.15                 hd6ba6f3_3    conda-forge
lerc                      4.0.0                hb486fe8_0    conda-forge
libass                    0.17.1               h80904bb_1    conda-forge
libcxx                    16.0.6               hd57cbcb_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.19                 ha4e1b8e_0    conda-forge
libexpat                  2.5.0                hf0c8a7f_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h0d85af4_5    conda-forge
libglib                   2.78.0               hc62aa5d_0    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.17                 hac89ed1_0    conda-forge
libidn2                   2.3.4                hb7f2c08_0    conda-forge
libjpeg-turbo             3.0.0                h0dc2134_1    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                hc929b4f_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.39               ha978bb4_0    conda-forge
libsqlite                 3.43.2               h92b6c6a_0    conda-forge
libtasn1                  4.19.0               hb7f2c08_0    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.6.0                h684deea_2    conda-forge
libunistring              0.9.10               h0d85af4_0    conda-forge
libvpx                    1.13.1               he965462_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.3.2                h0dc2134_0    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.15                 hb7f2c08_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.11.5               h3346baf_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               h8a1eda9_5    conda-forge
llvm-openmp               17.0.2               hff08bdf_0    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.3            py39hdc70f33_1    conda-forge
mkl                       2023.2.0         hfe8bc8c_50499    conda-forge
mkl-service               2.4.0            py39h6c40b1e_1  
mkl_fft                   1.3.8            py39h6c40b1e_0  
mkl_random                1.2.4            py39ha357a0b_0  
mpc                       1.3.1                h81bd1dd_0    conda-forge
mpfr                      4.2.0                h4f9bd69_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.4                  hf0c8a7f_0    conda-forge
nettle                    3.8.1                h96f3785_1    conda-forge
networkx                  3.1                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.26.0           py39h827a554_0  
numpy-base                1.26.0           py39ha186be2_0  
openh264                  2.3.1                hf0c8a7f_2    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.5.0                ha4da562_3    conda-forge
openssl                   3.1.3                h8a1eda9_0    conda-forge
p11-kit                   0.24.1               h65f8906_0    conda-forge
packaging                 23.2               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.40                h1c4e4bc_0    conda-forge
pillow                    10.1.0           py39hdd30358_0    conda-forge
pip                       23.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.42.2               he965462_0    conda-forge
pluggy                    1.3.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               hc929b4f_1001    conda-forge
pycosat                   0.6.6            py39hdc70f33_0    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 23.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1              pyha2e5f31_6    conda-forge
python                    3.9.18          h07e1443_0_cpython    conda-forge
python_abi                3.9                      4_cp39    conda-forge
pytorch                   2.1.0                   py3.9_0    pytorch
pyyaml                    6.0.1            py39hdc70f33_1    conda-forge
readline                  8.2                  h9e318b2_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.31.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml               0.17.35          py39hdc70f33_0    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.7            py39hdc70f33_2    conda-forge
setuptools                68.2.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
svt-av1                   1.7.0                he965462_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.12            pypyh9d50eac_103    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.10.0            h1c7c39f_1    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.13               hef22860_0    conda-forge
torchaudio                2.1.0                  py39_cpu    pytorch
torchvision               0.16.0                 py39_cpu    pytorch
tqdm                      4.66.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         4.8.0              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2023c                h71feb2d_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   2.0.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.41.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
x264                      1!164.3095           h775f41a_2    conda-forge
x265                      3.5                  hbb4e6a2_3    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.11               h0dc2134_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h35c211d_0    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.6                h775f41a_0    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h0d85af4_2    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.13               h8a1eda9_5    conda-forge
zstandard                 0.21.0           py39h5705987_1    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.5                h829000d_0    conda-forge
```

I have been tried everything what chat gpt told me. Creating new env with python 3.9
Updated pip, conda, libmamba, github

Comment: is it linux platform? may be you can check which python and compare path of python

Comment: it is macbook air

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the python from your currently active conda env. Notice the python that conda installed is version `3.9.18`:

```
python                    3.9.18          h07e1443_0_cpython    conda-forge
```

But what is being called when you write `(myenv) \____\_ \~ % python`  is another version (3.9.6):

```
Python 3.9.6 (default, Oct 18 2022, 12:41:40)
```

So either:

1. Your PATH is not correct, which would indicate that your conda did not activate the env correctly. Do `echo $PATH` and check that the folders of your env are in the front
2. You have an alias set up for `python`, something that some tutorials online suggest. type `type python` and check the output.

A workaround can be to call `${CONDA_PREFIX}/bin/python` and try your `import torch` there. This should call the python interpreter installed into your currently active env